# Focusing from up to down and not left to right in a table of text-fields when tabbing

Tags: php, html

I have an html form in the form of a table wherein the student must fill-up with his subjects (the form will look like a class schedule once complete). I'm having trouble with modifying the behavior of tab such that I want it to move vertically and not the default left to right to allow the user to fill up all the classes in this manner:

> ```
>        MON
> ```
>
> 7 - 8
>
> 8 - 9
>
> 9 - 10

etc. and not by

> ```
>        MON    TUES    WED
> ```
>
> 7-8

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Suggestions as to how I can also get a student's class schedule without using a table of textboxes  are also welcome.

**edit:**
Didn't see much use `tabindex`, because I'm creating my table in a left to right manner

```
for($h=0; $h<sizeof($time); $h++) {
        echo "<tr><td> " . $time[$h] . "</td>";
        for($i=0; $i<DAYS; $i++)
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='subject[]' id='subject' autocomplete='off' tabindex='" . $k . "'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Use `tabindex` attribute

Comment: Didn't work because I'm creating my table from left-to-right using a for loop.

Comment: Whilst you're in a forloop you can just attach `tabindex="'.$i.'"` though. And if you want it to run otherwise get a new counter which runs like 1/4/8/12 or something :) think creative!

Comment: You need to use this attribute on every field in your custom order.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you can add some value to keep the tabindex. For example, if you know that there are `$time` rows, you can use

```
for($h=0; $h<sizeof($time); $h++) {
    echo "<tr><td> " . $time[$h] . "</td>";
    for($i=0; $i<DAYS; $i++)
        echo "<td><input type='text'... tabindex='" . ($i*count($time)+$h+1) . "'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This `$i*count($time)+$h` would have unique tabindex then, while `$i` is a column and `$h` is a row.

**EDIT**

I edited the code as `tabindex` should not be `0` so `1` is added. The code here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c7i-120 is a working example of what you desire.

Comment: @Gannicus I'm glad it helps. Two pieces of advice: 1. you can calculate `sizeof($time)` (or `count($time)`) before the loop (in the fiddle there is `$howmanyrows` variable), so the code would be faster as number of rows would not be calculated each iteration; 2. Some people believe that `++$i` is faster than `$i++`.

Answer (score 3):

Give `tabindex` for that input textfields

```
<input type='text' tabindex="0">
<input type='text' tabindex="1">
<input type='text' tabindex="2">
```

Comment: Didn't work because I'm creating my table cells from left-to-right using a for loop.

Comment: @Gannicus It will work, you have to give tabindex in that for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use tabindex for these things. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: It never hurts to understand why you type certain things. Handing over code without explanation doesn't really give understanding in actions :-p

Comment: Handing over links to w3schools should get you banned :) They present themself as leading company for these sort of things but have more errors and security issues in their code than is good for you